# MS Access - Filter list based off checkboxes

Tags: database, ms-access

Alright so I've got a form that shows batch num, batch? check, job num, part num and org.... those things all come from a table which my form query is selecting from.
I want to filter this list based off when Batch? is checked

If Batch? is checked, then I only want the list to show me things that have the same part number and org as the item for which batch? was checked. 
If no Batch? is checked, then I want the list to show me everything.

Any tips?

Form view:

[image: Form view]

Datasheet:

[image: list]

Comment: So I think what I need to do is put a filter at the top of my form that I can use to filter my query results... and then populate that filter based off this check box. When the first item is checked it will filter to only show me things that are like that item and then any item that I check afterward would not change the filter output since they would be like the original selection.....?

Comment: Yes, you can use UNBOUND controls and code to set the check boxes. Is this a multi-user db? If so, users will conflict with each other in setting the field value.

Comment: It is multi user... what I have now is an unbound filter box at the top of the page... I populate that box based off the checkbox click and then I requery the form based off of what is in the filter.

Your statement about the field values would have applied if I was writing a string to a temp table and then filtering based off that table... correct?

Comment: No, if you are changing the value of the Batch_Checked field in order to select records, what if two users are trying to do this at the same time? They could change each others entries. Okay, if they only select one ItemID, the risk of conflict may be low. Are you trying to allow selection of multiple ItemNum? This check field seems to add an unnecessary layer of complexity. Users could just select an ItemNum from a combobox dropdown and filter is applied accordingly.